# automation of processes by python

Tags: python, qemu

I'm trying to write a python script that start a process and do some operations atferward. 
The commands that I want to automate by script are circled as red in the picture.
The problem is that after performing first command, qemu environment will be run and the other commands should be executed on the qemu environment. So I want to know how can I do these commands by an script in python? Because as I know I can do the first command but I do not know how can I do those commands when I am going to qemu environment.

[image]

Could you help me how can I do this process?

Comment: there is no need for the screenshot. Include the circled *text* into your question as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that came to mind was [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect), a quick search on google turned up this blog post  [automatically-testing-vms-using-pexpect-and-qemu](http://dummdida.tumblr.com/post/82368744933/automatically-testing-vms-using-pexpect-and-qemu) which seems to be pretty much along the lines of what you are doing:

```
import pexpect

image = "fedora-20.img"
user = "root"
password = "changeme"

# Define the qemu cmd to run
# The important bit is to redirect the serial to stdio
cmd = "qemu-kvm"
cmd += " -m 1024 -serial stdio -net user -net nic"
cmd += " -snapshot -hda %s" % image
cmd += " -watchdog-action poweroff"

# Spawn the qemu process and log to stdout
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child.logfile = sys.stdout

# Now wait for the login
child.expect('(?i)login:')

# And login with the credentials from above
child.sendline(user)
child.expect('(?i)password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('# ')

# Now shutdown the machine and end the process
if child.isalive():
    child.sendline('init 0')
    child.close()

if child.isalive():
    print('Child did not exit gracefully.')
else:
    print('Child exited gracefully.')
```

You could do it with `subprocess.Popen` also, checking the stdout for the `(qemu)` lines and writing to stdin. Something roughly like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

# pass initial command as list of individual args
p = Popen(["./tracecap/temu","-monitor",.....],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
# store all the next arguments to pass
args = iter([arg1,arg2,arg3])
# iterate over stdout so we can check where we are
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
    # if (qemu) is at the prompt, enter a command
    if line.startswith("(qemu)"):
        arg = next(args,"") 
        # if we have used all args break
        if not arg:
            break
        # else we write the arg with a newline
        p.stdin.write(arg+"\n")
    print(line)# just use to see the output
```

Where `args` contains all the next commands.

Comment: @user2942756, what is being outputted?

Comment: nothing. It is only show this line: QEMU 0.9.1 monitor - type 'help' for more information. Then wait for a long time and do not do any thing. It seems it can not write to qemu stdin

Comment: @user2942756, it should be able to, if you run the first command from a shell what output do you see immediately?

Comment: Actually are you not running the command `general/trace...` that you do not have circled? Is that not meant to be the first command to stdin?

Comment: it is loaded automatically because I used loadvm command option. That is why I have not circled it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82866/discussion-between-user2942756-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that Python has *batteries included*. Take a look of the [Suprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) in the standard lib. There a lot of pitfalls managing processes, and the module take care of them all.

You probably want to start a qemu process and send the next commands writing to its standard input (stdin). Subprocess module will allow you to do it. See that qemu has [command line options](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html) to connect to stdi: `-chardev stdio ,id=id`

Comment: Thanks for your info. I am doing something like this, but still I can not communicate to stdin:p = Popen([r"/home/bitblaze/temu-1.0/tracecap/temu","-snapshot","-monitor","stdio","-m","1024", "/home/hossein/windowsxp.qcow"],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='load_plugin /home/bitblaze/temu-1.0/tracecap/tracecap.so')[0]
print(stdout_data)

Comment: @user2942756: try to communicate through stdin outside of Python. So you can debug where is the problem. To do it try at the command line: echo <text to stdin> | temu <parameter to read input from stdin>